# Python scraper: How to go in a profile and extract data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making a python scraper for a project. I need to scrape some data from a Doctor Review site.

I've got code working for getting there Name, Specialties and Number of Reviews, but I need to enter each of their profile to get Phone Number and Address, I do not know how should I do it, do I need separate function to do it, or I can do it with this one?

Every kind of help will help me a lot.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


base_url = "https://www.ratemds.com/best-doctors/?page=1"
for page in range(1, 5, 1):
    r = requests.get(base_url)
    c = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
    all = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "search-item doctor-profile"})

    for item in all:
        try:
            print(item.find("a", {"class": "search-item-doctor-link"}).text)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            print(item.find("a", {"class": None}).text)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Just like you did with finding their data (name, specialties, number of reviews), you want to find the link to their profile. So find that in the page, then do another scrape on the profile page instead (for each of the doctor's profile pages), looking this time for the phone number and address

Comment: You're on the right path by grabbing `"search-item-doctor-link"` for each of the doctors. For the purpose of loading each doctor's page, instead of taking `item.find("a", {"class": "search-item-doctor-link"}).text`, you'll want to take `item.find("a", {"class": "search-item-doctor-link"})['href']`. Once you have that URL for each of the doctors, you'll need to use `requests.get()` again and parse with BeautifulSoup. That said, I took a look at one of the pages, and it seems that the site makes it difficult to grab that information in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 0):

According to @cpander just store all `item.find("a", {"class": "search-item-doctor-link"})['href']` and run requests.get() again with stored Urls.
Just a short example for getting the phone number:

`item.find("div", attrs={"doctordetail":".1.0.0.0.2.2.0.1.1.0.0.1:1.0"}")`

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank him espicaly for his idea suggestion.

This was the way I did:

```
for item in all:
    try:
        n = item.find("a", {"class": "search-item-doctor-link"})
        a = n.get('href')
        print("https://www.ratemds.com/"+a)
    except:
        pass
```

And I get all the link for there profiles, the rest I know.

Thanks to all, that offered there help :)